# unable to mock generic object creation

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, generic-collections

I want to mock dao creation for following method.

```
private ReturnType createTenant(){

TenantDto tenantDto = new TenantDto();
        TenantGroupDto tenantUserGroupDto = new TenantGroupDto(DEFAULT_USER_GROUP_NAME,Type.HUMAN,DEFAULT_USER_GROUP_DESCR, true);
        TenantGroupDto tenantDeviceGroupDto = new TenantGroupDto(DEFAULT_DEVICE_GROUP_NAME,Type.DEVICE,DEFAULT_DEVICE_GROUP_DESCR, true);

        Set<TenantGroupDto> tenantGroups = new HashSet<TenantGroupDto>();

        tenantGroups.add(tenantUserGroupDto);
        tenantGroups.add(tenantDeviceGroupDto);
        tenantDto.setTenantGroup(tenantGroups);          
        tenantDto = tenantDao.create(tenantDto);
        return someOtherOperation(tenantDto);
}
```

I'm able to mock rest of the things however. I'm unable to mock generic creation.

i.e.

```
Set<TenantGroupDto> tenantGroups = new HashSet<TenantGroupDto>();
```

It is required to be mocked since tenantGroups is parameter to

```
tenantDao.create(tenantDto);
```

Most of the links/questions I search about are when the generic object gets returned from some method. I couldn't find any solution to creation of generic object. Any help is appreciated.

Thx in Advance.

Comment: There's really no reason to mock something like this.

Comment: Generics are used just to guarantee type safety. They are forgotten at runtime, I think.

Comment: Luis is right, you would have to mock the creation of all HashSets using PowerMock or something - I am also interested in why you want to mock a HashSet...

Comment: This is clearly a XY problem; you want to mock something which means you use that in tests. What is the test? Changes are good enough that mocking object creation is not what you want, but using pure mocks instead.

Comment: The only thing I could realistically see mocking is `tenantDao.create`, but it does have an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/175248) vibe to it.  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Makoto to mock tenantDao.create(tenantDto); tenantDto should be equal to mocked tenantDto. so to match my object wtih object there i need to mock HashSet<TenantGroupDto> as well

Comment: It would be better if you gave us the entire method you want to test.  Mocking is only appropriate in certain contexts; namely, you've got some sort of service or DTO layer that you have already tested and don't want to spin up real instances of.  If all `tenantDao.create` does is return the same object back, and you want to mock it, then there's no reason to worry about the object being created - when you mock, you're *giving* it the object that it should expect.

Comment: @Makoto added complete method. I wanted to mock Dao.create() with dto object as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to create a mock of a generic class.

```
@Mock
Set<TenantGroupDto> tenantGroups 

@Before
public void init(){
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void myTest(){
when(tenantGroups....
}
```

Comment: Thx for answer.
I never thought it will be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito (alone) can't truly mock the *instantiation* of objects, Generics or otherwise (although [you can get close](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation)).

This is a classic reason why people use the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29), allowing pluggable factories to allow differing types of objects decided at runtime, or to allow neat, encapsulated testing with mocks / stubs like in this situation.

As for the collections (e.g. `HashSet`), there is very little reason to test *them*; just make sure your (domain) objects are fully tested, and you should be covering the right code in your tests.